# Printing a function and assigning a function to variable and printing the variable giving different outputs

Tags: r, function

I have written the code below in R. Can any one explain why executing a function and assigning the function to a variable and printing the variable is giving different results.

Please see the code below.

```
fc <- function(num) {
      hello <- "Hello, world!\n"
      for(i in seq_len(num)) {
          cat(hello)
          }
      chars <- nchar(hello) * num
      chars
      }
```

Output of fc(3)

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
[1] 42
```

Now I am assigning the `fc(3)` to a variable alpha and when printing alpha, see what is the output.

```
alpha<- fc(3)
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!

> print(alpha)
[1] 42
```

Comment: (1) You are not assigning the *function* to a variable, you are assigning the *result of calling it* to a variable. (2) You say that you see different results, but the results you’ve printed are *the same* in both cases.

Comment: @KonradRudolph So you mean the final return statement alone will be assigned to the variable. May i know alpha <-fc(3) is giving me Hello World output at that expression ?

Comment: R doesn’t really have “return statements” like other languages do, but your description is otherwise correct: the value of the last expression is the value returned by a function. The `cat` function is unrelated to that: it does not *return* a value, it directly prints it.

Answer (score 1):

`print` (or `cat`) is different from `return`.

`print` (or `cat`) just prints the value in the console whereas `return` value is what is actually returned from the function and can be stored by assigning it to an object (`a <- fc(3)`).

For your example, you can add as many `print` or `cat` statements in the function but the only value returned is the last line in the function or the one with an explicit `return` statement.

```
fc <- function(num) {
   hello <- "Hello, world!\n"
   cat(rep(hello, num))
   cat('Printing more\n')
   print('new print')
   return(nchar(hello) * num)
}

a <- fc(3)
#Hello, world!
# Hello, world!
# Hello, world!
#Printing more
#[1] "new print"

a
#[1] 42
```

Comment: I think adding `return` (= premature function termination) to the mix adds confusion rather than clarity. As I said in my other comment, R functions don’t have “return statements”, they simply have *values*. That mental model is much closer to how functions are defined in mathematics and should be easier to understand for beginners (unless they’ve been “tainted” by imperative programming languages).

Comment: Probably yes, but there is also another opinion that it is better to have an explicit `return` in all the functions so that you know exactly what is being returned instead of relying on last line of the function. Although I believe both the approaches are subjective.